# `html-loader` overwrite `HtmlWebpackPlugin` `<%= %>` expression

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

I am using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` in webpack and below is its configuration:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body',
        sdk: '/mylib.js'
      })
```

In my `html` I define the `script` tag as:

```
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.sdk %>"></script>
```

webpack will replace the `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.sdk %>` with `/mylib.js`. However it doesn't work once I add the `html-loader` plugin as below:

```
{
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'html-loader',
              options: {
                attrs: 'img:src'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

The reason I use `html-loader` is to parse the `img src` tag on html file. But it conflicts with `HtmlWebpackPlugin` `<%= ... %>` expression. How can I make both of them work?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution i found for this is to rename your template with .ejs extention.
This will kick in html-webpack-plugin (as it's an fallback ejs-loader), and then after it process all the <%= %> it will kick in the html-loader.

This way the html-webpack-plugin will running first and then followed by html loader.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: 'index.html.ejs',  // don't forget to rename the actual file
    inject: 'body',
    sdk: '/mylib.js'
  })
```

Comment: With this method, html-loader will not insert image names/links anymore.

Comment: @Mecanik we could still import images, using ejs syntax, example:
<img src="<%= require('../images/image-name.jpg') %>" />

Answer (score 0):

I would give the property `ignoreCustomFragments` of html-loader a try. According to the [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader), you can pass it as an option and the loader ignores some parts, depending on a RegExp: `ignoreCustomFragments: [/<%=.*%>/]`

Comment: Webpack 5: ValidationError: Invalid options object. HTML Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
   - options has an unknown property 'ignoreCustomFragments'. These properties are valid:
     object { preprocessor?, sources?, minimize?, esModule? }

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine three steps.

**First**, you need HtmlWebpackPlugin. as indicated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264384/9363857

**Second**, you activate html-loader. This leads to the strange result of having a line like

```
module.exports=.....
```

in the middle of your html (replacing the require), which is not really what you want.

So, **third**, you need to translate this back to html, for which you need to add an extract-loader. As in:

```
test: /\.(html)$/, use:  [ 'extract-loader',  { loader: 'html-loader' } ]
```